# When File Selected Change Label Contents jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

So, I'm attempting to make my file upload input look a little bit better than the default buttons. All is going well, however, I can't seem to find a jQuery script which can do what I want it to do.

What I want to happen is, when a file isn't selected, I would like the label to display "Choose an avatar", but when a file is selected, I would like it to display the files name, i.e: "example.png" instead of "Choose an avatar".

This is my HTML:

```
<form action="" method="post" class="avatar-form-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input id="avatar-file" type="file" name="avatar">
    <label for="avatar-file">Choose An Avatar</label>
</form>
```

Also, if the user selects multiple files, I would like it to say "Too many files selected."

All help is appreciated as I am new to jQuery.

Comment: Try this ... https://jsfiddle.net/khwnps20/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set `text()` of label as `val` of input, and for multiple files you would have to use `multiple`

```js
$('input').change(function() {
  $(this).next('label').text($(this).val());
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" method="post" class="avatar-form-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input id="avatar-file" type="file" name="avatar">
  <label for="avatar-file">Choose An Avatar</label>
</form>
```

If you want to hide default `file` input's text you can use `color: transparent` in CSS [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/768/)

Comment: unfortunately this didn't work. :( still acting the same as before

Comment: all of it. the label's contents were not changed when the user selected a file

Comment: Did you include `JQuery`?

Comment: never mind. I just fixed it. however, I would like to get rid of the "C:\fakepath\" bit. how would I do that? do you think you could edit your answer?